# Combining sets together

Tags: java

I currently have a functioning program that will calculate the price of drinks. Here is a snippet of how the drinks are created.

```
Drink coke = new Drink ("thick", 1.50);
        Coke.setCost(1.50);
        Coke.getType();
```

I'm now required to make another class. Inside this class must contain pre-set drinks, these pre-set drinks must be developed from the drinks that i have already defined in my other class ( like above )

Here is my attempt at doing this. However, it doesn't seem to recognise the coke and fanta that i have introduced in my other class.

```
Drink coFanta = new Drink
Drink.getType(coke);
Drink.getType(fanta);
```

Could someone please give me advice on how i'm able to ( in a new class) apply my drinks defined in my previous class to create one drink. E.g. if i want a predefined drink consists of fanta and coke. My attempt would be like above, so coFanta would consist of coke and fanta. So if a person were to purchase coFanta they'd receive a drink with coke and fanta.

Any advice appreciated

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your second code snippet isn't syntactically valid. What do you mean by "should fanta not = fanta + coke"?

Comment: It would depend on the implementation of Drink/Coke and any other classes you're using. Do you have those? Also, what do you mean by "not work"?

Comment: It sounds as if you are saying you want to do something like create a drink which shares the properties of both coke and fanta.  You would need to create a new type or some means for achieving this.  Your goal sounds like it is too abstract.

Comment: @Vivin Paliath - Well, the aim is to create a drink with multiple other drinks. So i was implying that coFanta** should in real terms contain coke and fanta. It's an ordering system. So, the user should be able to purchase a preset drink which contains multiple other drinks in the one

Comment: Edited, hopefully it'll be more clearer and suitable now..

Comment: Anyone that can help, much appreciated.